# making a REST API call to Bitbucket Server and trying to pass JSON payload causes an error

Tags: json, curl, bitbucket, bitbucket-server

I am trying to make rest API call to Bitbucket Server to delete a pull request.  I am trying to do it all in one line curl command but getting an error when trying to pass json payload with -d flag.  Can you please help.

Rest API instructions in BitBucket instruct to pass

A body containing the version of the pull request must be provided with this request.
{
    "version": 1
}

My command:

curl -u 'user:password' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d \'{"version":0}\' -X DELETE "https://bitbucketaddress.com/rest/api/1.0/projects/PROJECT/repos/test-repo/pull-requests/19"

Error that I am getting:

{"errors":[{"context":null,"message":"Unexpected character (''' (code 39)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [Source: com.atlassian.stash.internal.web.util.web.CountingServletInputStream@5ba3ef6e; line: 1, column: 2]","exceptionName":"org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException"}]}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your quotes are a little off. Try:

```
-d "{\"version\":0}"
```

or

```
-d "{'version':0}"
```

instead?